# How to suppress "UseSparseArrays" for a statement?

Tags: android, android-lint

Some lints can be suppressed for a statement. E. g., "division by zero" lint:

```
//noinspection divzero
int i = 3 / 0;
```

But some lints can't be suppressed for a statement in the same way. E. g.:

```
//noinspection UseSparseArrays   <-- Has no effect
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
```

What is the difference between these two lints? 
Can we suppress lints like "UseSparseArrays" for a statement in some other way? (Don't want to suppress it for the whole method).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the difference between these two lints?

After some research, I found an answer:

- `divzero` is Java compiler lint warning (see `divzero` among [Xlint options](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html#xlintwarnings)).
- `UseSparseArrays` is Android lint warning (see `UseSparseArrays` among [Andoid lint warnings](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-checks))

> Can we suppress lints like "UseSparseArrays" for a statement in some
>   other way?

According to [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint#java) Android lint warnings can be suppressed **only** for a class or a method with `@SuppressLint`.